# Angular Default value dropdown using an Object

Tags: arrays, angular, string, object, dropdown

I am using Angular Material (latest stable version) for my project and I am not able to set the default value in the dropdown by using an Object. My code:

TS-FILE:

```
selectedObject: any;
selectedObjectList: any = [{ key: 1, value: 'One' }, { key: 2, value: 'Two' }, { key: 3, value: 'Three' }];

changeMatObject(value: any) {
  console.log('MatObject value: ', value);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedObject = { key: 1, value: 'One'};
}
```

HTML-FILE:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selectedObject">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let selectedObject of selectedObjectList; let i = index" value="{{selectedObject.key}}"
                (click)="changeMatObject(selectedObject.value)">
                {{selectedObject.value}}
       </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Apparently it is possible to set the default value when the value in the HTML [(value)] is set to a string like this example:

TS-FILE:

```
selectedString: any;
selectedStringList: any = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

changeMatString(value: any) {
  console.log('MatString value: ', value);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.selectedObject = 'One';
}
```

HTML-FILE:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selectedString">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let selectedString of selectedStringList; let i = index" value="{{selectedString}}"
                (click)="changeMatString(selectedString)">
                {{selectedString}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is a small piece of code but with larger lists/objects it can be difficult. Can someone explain what the difference is creating a dropdownlist with array filled with strings and an array filled with objects and why it isnt possible to set the default value in object dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [(ngModel)] in place of [(value)] ?

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedString">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let string of selectedStringList; let i = index" value="{{string}}"
                (click)="changeMatString(string)">
                {{string}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a few typos (and re-used `selectedObject` in your template) and you need a way to compare objects:

## HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selectedObject" [compareWith]="compareObjects">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let selectableObject of selectedObjectList; let i = index" [value]="selectableObject"
                    (click)="changeMatObject(selectableObject.value)">
            {{selectableObject.value}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

(Note the difference between `selectedObject` and `selectableObject`, the `[value]` binding and the `compareObjects` function)

## TypeScript

```
public compareObjects = function (option, value): boolean {
    return option.key === value.key;
}
```